# Migrating users with social login to Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to migrate user accounts from our database to Azure AD B2C following an article and simple app that's coupled with the article -- see below.

All user accounts we have in our database used social login e.g. Google, LinkedIn and Facebook. I'm looking at the code in the migration app and I don't see any reference to user's social login. I don't see any properties for login type or anything like that.

How will I specify how the user registered in our system and has been using his/her social account to log into our app? The migration structure seems very simple i.e. just name, last name, email, etc.

I do NOT have to use this app but not sure if there's a simpler way to handle this.

The article I'm following is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration

And here's a link to the simple migration app: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/scenarios/aadb2c-user-migration

Comment: Hi  Sam, did you get any solution for this , we are same problem .

Comment: No, we ended up abandoning AB2C all together because it was one obstacle after another.

Answer (score 0):

For a social account, Azure AD B2C finds the user object using a composite key that includes the social user identifier (e.g. the "id" claim that is issued by the social identity provider) and the social identity provider name (e.g. "facebook.com").

This composite key is stored in the "alternativeSecurityId" attribute of the user object.

Currently, you can't read or write this "alternativeSecurityId" attribute of the user object using the Azure AD Graph API, which means you can't migrate the social accounts from your existing identity store using a similar method to that described in [the user migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration).

Answer (score -2):

> I don't see any reference to user's social login. I don't see any
>   properties for login type or anything like that.

**About migration:** Azure AD B2C can let social accounts to sign up and sign in . For your scenario, after migrating users to Azure AD B2C, the users from any social identities can sign in the Application in your Azure AD B2C. (You can also change your policy to check and set the user migration status.)

**About where users information are stored:** After migrating, all the users can be seen in the **`Users and Groups`** of Azure AD B2C. Additional,There is an App called **`b2c-extensions-app`**, is visible in App registrations. It is used by the Azure AD B2C service to store information about users and custom attributes.

**About Login type:** Also, you may want to know which properties for login type you can choose, Email address or Username. This configuration can be done in Azure Portal. 
**Go to Azure Portal > You B2C tenant > Identity providers > local accounts > Choose Email or User name for sign-up and sign-in.**

[image]

> How will I specify how the user registered in our system and has been
>   using his/her social account to log into our app? The migration
>   structure seems very simple i.e. just name, last name, email, etc.

Yes, the migration is very simple. If you want to specify how the users to sign-up and sign-in , you need to built-in [**Sign-up or Sign-in policies for those users**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies). Also, you can use [**Custom policies**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom).

Comment: I don’t think I made my question clear enough. What I’m trying to understand is after I migrate my users how would AAD B2C identify my user who was using his LinkedIn account to log into my app? Does it use email address to find an existing user?

Comment: I may have many John Smith’s in my database. One may have used his LinkedIn account to access my app while another John Smith may have used his Google account. Both are existing users so they’ll be in the directory. How will AAD B2C know which one is which. Currently, in our DB, we run a search by user ID we get from social provider which uniquely identifies the user.

Comment: Hi,@Sam. Sorry for my misunderstanding. Yes, After migration, you needn't add  Identity providers in Azure AD B2C. If you choose Email to login, Azure AD B2C will searches for the email address directly.

Comment: Here’s my concern: I know for a fact that some users register with different social providers using different email addresses. For example, Jane Doe may have used her work email to register with a LinkedIn and Gmail email for Facebook. In both cases, it’s the same user. If this user forgets that she uses her LinkedIn account to access my app and clicks the Google icon, she’d end up registering as a new user because AAD B2C is relying solely on email to uniquely identify users. I’m concerned about these scenarios.

Comment: Hi, @Sam .I understand what you worry about. Indeed, each user in Azure AD B2C has more information than just Username or email address. each user has one unique **Object ID**. Also,  different users cannot use same attribute to login. Such as they cannot use same email address to login. the Name of users can be same. But their login attribute cannot be same.

Comment: I’m not concerned about different users getting mixed up. My concern is creating unnecessary duplicate registrations for the same user because the user made a mistake and clicked a different social provider than the one she normally uses. When a returning user comes back to my app and clicks a social provider, AAD B2C has no idea what the ObjectId for that user is in the directory. It will simply make a call to the social provider and receive user’s personal details. This is the part I’m trying to get really clear on. How does AAD then query the directory for the user? Is it by email?

Comment: Hi, @Sam. I see !! This is a very good question , I did think it before . Just wait a moment and let me do a test. I will keep you updated.

Comment: Thank you. My guess is that AAD will either run a query by user’s email or username coming from the social provider to see if this is a returning user or a new one. If AAD doesn’t store which social provider was used during registration, it must use email.

Comment: Hi,@Sam . I'm back . I found that it also links to your application. Since your  application is also migrated. I don't have such a app for test. Sorry for that. But I got a new knowledge. AAD will check if the email address is unique. When sign-in, AAD will query the user by email. But I'm not sure whether the user can login with that email address via social accounts  button. If this is important for you,I suggest you can call Azure Support for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think Azure B2C is the right answer for us. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi @Sam Are you planning to use custom policies?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett I feel AAD B2C is a pretty decent solution for most apps but I'm trying to create something a bit more sophisticated and I don't think AAD B2C would give me the necessary flexibility to create the experience I want in my app.